# Can IIS Automatic Recycle fail or timeout?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-7, timeout, asp

We are an IIS7 shop and we have our application pool set to auto recycle nightly at 1AM.  During this last recycle, the site was actually brought 'down'.  When the outage was reported, we manually recycled the app pool and it brought the site back up again.

The odd thing here is that the site was working FINE with no errors until our nightly recycle happened.  I want to track down what happened here.  Is there any way the automatic recycle can fail or maybe timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can. If it gets stuck, it'll timeout. you'll see something like this in the event log..

Event Type:       Warning
Event Source:    W3SVC
Event Category: None
Event ID:          1012
Date:                3/16/2010
Time:                12:00:04 PM
User:                N/A
Computer:         YourWebServer
Description:
A process serving application pool 'Your App Pool' exceeded time limits during start up. The process id was '5004